# How do I add a pretty printer for a generic type to fsi?

Tags: f#, fsi

In F# Interactive (fsi), you can use `AddPrinter` or `AddPrinterTransformer` to provide pretty printing for a type in the interactive session. How can I add such a printer for a generic type? Using the wildcard `_` for the type doesn't work:

```
> fsi.AddPrinter(fun (A : MyList<_>) -> A.ToString());;
```

The printer just isn't used.

Putting in a type parameter also gives a warning:

```
> fsi.AddPrinter(fun (A : MyList<'T>) -> A.ToString());;

  fsi.AddPrinter(fun (A : MyList<'T>) -> A.ToString());;
  -------------------------------^^

d:\projects\stdin(70,51): warning FS0064: This construct causes code
to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type
variable 'T been constrained to be type 'obj'.
```

which is not what I want, either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. A type arg requires a concrete type.

Comment: Can you override `ToString` for `MyList<'T>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't work for the general case, but since it appears you're working with your own type (at least in your example), and assuming you don't want to affect `ToString`, you could do something like this:

```
type ITransformable =
  abstract member BoxedValue : obj

type MyList<'T>(values: seq<'T>) =
  interface ITransformable with
    member x.BoxedValue = box values

fsi.AddPrintTransformer(fun (x:obj) ->
  match x with
  | :? ITransformable as t -> t.BoxedValue
  | _ -> null)
```

Output:

```
> MyList([1;2;3])
val it : MyList<int> = [1; 2; 3]
```

For a third-party generic type you could use `AddPrintTransformer` and reflection to get the value to be displayed. An interface is just easier if you have the source.

Comment: Thanks. But why do you declare `AddPrintTransformer`'s parameter to have type `obj`? Why not use `ITransformable` directly there? Or even use `AddPrinter` with a function that takes an `ITransformable`?

Comment: It's `obj` because I first went down the road of using reflection. You can probably change it to `ITransformable`. I think `AddPrintTransformer` is better for what you're trying to do because, in most cases, delegating to a display-able value is sufficient.